# Binding parameter as PostgreSQL array

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to bind a prepared statement parameter which is a "multidimensional" PostgreSQL array. Here's an array example (column type is `numeric[]`):

```
{{1,10},{2,20}}
```

How do I bind a value like that using a prepared statement? I tried:

```
stmt.setObject(1, "{{1,10},{2,20}}", Types.ARRAY);
```

It didn't work:

> Cannot cast an instance of java.lang.String to type Types.ARRAY

Any ideas?

Comment: something like this: `stmt.setObject(1, new Integer[][] {{1,10},{2,20}}, Types.ARRAY)`?

Comment: Doesn't work, I tried BigDecimal[][] as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try something like this (untested):

```
                ------------------ your connection
                V
Array inArray = conn.createArrayOf("integer", new Integer[][] {{1,10},{2,20}});
stmt.setArray(1, inArray);
```

Links:

- [Postgres and multi-dimensions arrays in JDBC](http://tonaconsulting.com/postgres-and-multi-dimensions-arrays-in-jdbc)
- [Passing Array from Java to Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/49107A7D.3050206@gmail.com)