# Postgresql JDBC Table Valued Parameters

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql, jdbc, plpgsql

**MSSQL** has a great feature called **Table Valued Parameters**. It allows you to pass a table of a custom data to stored procedures and functions.

I was wondering what is the equivalent in **PostgreSQL**, if one exists, using JDBC?
I know about the option of passing **arrays** as function parameters, but that seems limited to **PostgreSQL** data types.

Consider the following PL/pgSQL code:

```
CREATE  TYPE number_with_time AS(
_num   float,
_date  timestamp
);
```

and this function header:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(arr number_with_time[])
```

Can anyone post a Java code using JDBC driver of calling that function with an array of the user defined data type?

Comment: There is no direct equivalent I think, but you could use a **global** temporary table as a replacement for this.

Comment: can you provide some code sample for that?

Comment: The array of a composite type is also good option, and you can work with it in your function like a result set with `SELECT * FROM unnest(arr)` (though maybe not the most memory efficient way)

Comment: If you choose arrays, you can call this in sql with f.ex. `ARRAY[(1, 'now'), (2, 'now')]::number_with_time[]` - or create an array from a result set, with `array_agg(("float_val", "timestamp_val")::number_with_time)`

Comment: pozs - I'm not sure this answers my question. Since my issue is how to use the JDBC driver to pass this array as the parameter, can you provide the matching JAVA code to your comment?

Comment: @Orr with prepared statements? Just use `"... ARRAY[(?, ?), (?, ?)]::number_with_time[] ..."` in your query. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want to pass values **from the client**. If the values exist in the database already there are other, simpler ways.

#### Syntax for *array of composite_type*

> I know about the option of passing arrays as function parameters, but
> that seems limited to PostgreSQL data types.

What you can pass seems to be limited by [Java Types and JDBC Types](http://www.cab.u-szeged.hu/WWW/java/jdk/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.doc.html#1004752), and there does not seem be provisions for array types, not to speak of arrays of composite values ...

However, you can always pass a `text` representation. I am building on two basic facts:

1. Quoting [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html):

> Arrays of any built-in or user-defined base type, enum type, **or
> composite type** can be created. Arrays of domains are not yet supported.

Bold emphasis mine. Therefore, after you have created the type `number_with_time` as defined in your question, or defined a table with the same columns which registers the row type in the system automatically, you can also use the array type `number_with_time[]`.

2. There is a **`text`** representation for *every* value.

Therefore, there is also a text representation for `number_with_time[]`:

```
'{"(1,2014-04-20 20:00:00)","(2,2014-04-21 21:00:00)"}'::number_with_time[]
```

#### Function call

The actual function call depends on the return values defined in your function - which is hidden in your question.

To avoid complications from array handling in JDBC, pass the `text` representation. Create the function taking a `text` parameter.

I am not going to use the name "date" for a `timestamp`. Working with this slightly adjusted type definition:

```sql
CREATE TYPE number_with_time AS(
   _num float
 , _ts  timestamp
);
```

Simple SQL function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc_sql(_arr_txt text)
  RETURNS integer       -- example
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
   SELECT sum(_num)::int
   FROM   unnest (_arr_txt::number_with_time[]) x
   WHERE  _ts > '2014-04-19 20:00:00';
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT myfunc_sql('{"(1,2014-04-20 20:00:00)","(2,2014-04-21 21:00:00)"}');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c901fb89523967fa9b05454864ab6090)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d27773/1)</sub>

Demonstrating:

- above SQL function
- PL/pgSQL variant
- a couple of syntax variants for the array of composite type
- the function calls

Call the function like any other function taking a simple `text` parameter:

```
CallableStatement myProc = conn.prepareCall("{ ? = call myfunc_sql( ? ) }");
myProc.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
// you have to escape double quotes in a Java string!
myProc.setString(2, "{\"(1,2014-04-20 20:00:00)\",\"(2,2014-04-21 21:00:00)\"}");
myProc.execute();
String mySum = myProc.getInt(1);
myProc.close();
```

[Details in the Postgres JDBC manual here.](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/92/callproc.html)

Example to return a whole table via JDBC:

- [Return rows from a PL/pgSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862936/return-rows-from-a-pl-pgsql-function/11867138#11867138)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
                ------------------ your connection
                V
Array inArray = conn.createArrayOf("integer", new Integer[][] {{1,10},{2,20}});
stmt.setArray(1, inArray);
```

A sample method you could use to build your test:

```
    public void testInsertMultiDimension() throws Exception {

            Connection c = getConnection();

            PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO sal_emp VALUES ('multi_Bill',?,?);");
            Array intArray = c.createArrayOf("integer", new Integer[] {1000,1000,1000,1000});
            String[][] elements = new String[2][];
            elements[0] = new String[] {"meeting_m","lunch_m"};
            elements[1] = new String[] {"training_m","presentation_m"};

            //Note - although this is a multi-dimensional array, we still supply the base element of the array
            Array multiArray = c.createArrayOf("text", elements);
            stmt.setArray(1, intArray);
            stmt.setArray(2, multiArray);
            stmt.execute();
            //Note - free is not implemented
            //myArray.free();
            stmt.close();
            c.close();
    }
```

Helpful links:

- [Binding parameter as PostgreSQL array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658107/binding-parameter-as-postgresql-array)
- [Postgres and multi-dimensions arrays in JDBC](http://tonaconsulting.com/postgres-and-multi-dimensions-arrays-in-jdbc/)
- [Passing Array from Java to Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/49107A7D.3050206@gmail.com)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is PostgreSQL can use table or complex type as function's parameter or "table or complex type"'s array as function's paramter?
postgresql all support. and when you create a table, it's auto create an complex type named same as tablename.
like  :

```
digoal=# create table tbl123(id int, info text);
CREATE TABLE
digoal=# select typname from pg_type  where typname='tbl123';
 typname 
---------
 tbl123
(1 row)
```

and you can use this type in function direct.
for exp :

```
digoal=# create or replace function f_tbl123(i tbl123) returns tbl123 as $$  
  declare
  begin
  return i;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
digoal=# insert into tbl123 values (1,'test'),(2,'test2');
INSERT 0 2
digoal=# select f_tbl123(t) from tbl123 t;
 f_tbl123  
-----------
 (1,test)
 (2,test2)
(2 rows)
```

the array is also can used in postgresql function.
if you don't known how array construct in java, i think this exp can help you.

```
digoal=# select (unnest('{"(1,abc)","(2,ww)"}'::tbl123[])).*;
 id | info 
----+------
  1 | abc
  2 | ww
(2 rows)

digoal=# select '{"(1,abc)","(2,ww)"}'::tbl123[];
        tbl123        
----------------------
 {"(1,abc)","(2,ww)"}
(1 row)
digoal=# select array['(1,abc)','(2,ww)'];
        array         
----------------------
 {"(1,abc)","(2,ww)"}
(1 row)

digoal=# select array['(1,abc)','(2,ww)']::tbl123[];
        array         
----------------------
 {"(1,abc)","(2,ww)"}
(1 row)
digoal=# select (unnest(array['(1,abc)','(2,ww)'])::tbl123).*;
 id | info 
----+------
  1 | abc
  2 | ww
(2 rows)
```

Comment: My goal was to get a JAVA example of passing an array of custom data types to PL/pgSQL function, I don't think this helps..

Comment: @Orr - did mange to path array of custom Java objects to your PostgreSQL function? If yes then how ?

Comment: @robert - actually no, none of the answers here solved it but I just found a way around it for now. Not sure that there is an easy solution..

Comment: I don't see how this helps passing a type from java to pg, please read the question carefully before attempting to answer it

Comment: @robert can you share your solution using Java example?