# Insert and Retrieve data from postgresql array - jsp

Tags: postgresql, jsp, servlets, jdbc

How to write insert/update/delete/select postgresl Text array?

Assume I have a table as following:

```
CREATE TABLE classes (
   students     TEXT[] not null DEFAULT '{}'
);
```

Will this is a correct syntax for insertion using servlet?

```
...
String student_names = "{a, b, c, d}";    
String sql = "INSERT INTO classes (students) VALUES(?)";
preparedStatement = conn.executeQuery(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, student_names);
...
```

Then how can I select or update the index in the array? I read the doc not really know how to write the query for it. I tried to search on google but couldn't find a good resource about it neither.

Comment: keywords for google search are `postgres` `jdbc` `array` . See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658107/binding-parameter-as-postgresql-array and  http://tech.valgog.com/2009/02/getting-arrays-from-postgresql-database.html

Comment: You must use the JDBC-standard array management facilities.